# c++ How to wait for multiple mouse clicks

Tags: c++, cimg

I want to draw a Triangle in CImg library. However, I do not know how to write the code that will allow me to draw the triangle using three mouse clicks.
The code in the documentation is this:

```
 while (!main_disp.is_closed() && !draw_disp.is_closed()) 
{
main_disp.wait();
if (main_disp.button() && main_disp.mouse_y()>=0)
```

http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html

But it is for one mouse click, which I implemented successfully to draw a circle on the mouse click. But to do for three mouse clicks or two has proven to be difficult for me.

I also have the problem of inputting the color I want. I wrote red for example as:

```
const unsigned char red[] = {250, 0, 0};
```

Then I want the user to choose which color, enter his choice(assume it's red) and then pass this definition of red into the image.

Anyone can help with this ?!

Comment: Your second question is entirely distinct from your first. Please ask it in another post.

Answer (score 3):

If you know how to detect when the mouse button is clicked, you can store information about that click for later. For example, you can store previous mouse clicks in a `deque`.

```
struct point
{
    int x,y;
};

...

std::deque<point> clicks;

while (!main_disp.is_closed() && !draw_disp.is_closed()) 
{
    main_disp.wait();
    if (main_disp.button())
    {
        clicks.push_front({mouse_disp.mouse_x(), mouse_disp.mouse_y()});

        if (clicks.size() >= 3)
        {
            // draw a triangle using clicks[0], clicks[1] and clicks[2]
        }        
    }
}
```